# Wiremock startup fails with error "is not a valid match operation"

Tags: wiremock

I have added wiremock dependency in a spring boot app and started adding json configurations to match my incoming requests so that I can return mocked responses.
However upon adding the follwoing request_matcher, the app fails to boot

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/someapi/searchTimeslot",
    "method": "GET",
    "queryParameters": {
      "latest": {
        "or": [
          {
            "absent": true
          },
          {
            "doesNotMatch": "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z$"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 422,
    "jsonBody": [{"code": 422, "detail": "Invalid Parameter Value", "field": "latest", "message": "An allowed parameter was assigned an invalid value"}],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is the request to be matched when a query param named "latest" is either absent or does not match a timestamp pattern.

this is exactly as stated in the [documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#logical-and-and-or)

but the spring boot app fails to start with the following error

`get-timeslot-422-invalid-latest-date.json:\n{\"or\":[{\"absent\":true},{\"doesNotMatch\":\"^\\\\d{4}-\\\\d{2}-\\\\d{2}T\\\\d{2}:\\\\d{2}:\\\\d{2}Z$\"}]} is not a valid match operation`
please excuse the escaped sequences and quotation marks. Its just how log formatting is done in this app.

spring boot version : 2.7.10
wiremock dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
  <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
  <version>2.27.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like this *may* be a WireMock bug with the logical OR operator. If you reverse the order of your objects in the OR array, the app should start up.

```
...
"or": [
  {
    "doesNotMatch": "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z$"
  },
  {
    "absent": true
  }
]
...
```

The above loaded for me (WireMock 2.35.0), but I was encountering the same error as you were when the `absent: true` object was first.

Comment: Thanks @agoff 
reversing the order had no effect in version 2.27.2. So as you suggested, I had to upgrade wiremock version to 2.35.0 and kept the absent check at the end. 
I wonder this does not exist as an issue on their github page. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Logical AND and OR were added in 2.28.0, so this may have been a compound issue :D

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now in [#2236](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/2236) and will be released in WireMock 3.0.0-beta-11

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Will upgrade once the stable version is out